I’m looking for a word that describes a decision being imposed on you unwillingly
A word that implies a decision has been imposed on you against your will and perhaps accepted against your better judgment.

"infers" or "implies"?

What's wrong with "impose"?

Queen Victoria got her way by her not so gentle insistence. Hers was what was called a Whim of Iron.

Can you expand on the question? Maybe add a sentence where you need to use the word. It is unclear whether looking for a verb for the act of imposing, or a noun for the imposition itself.

Adding an example sentence would be a good idea.

Welcome to ELU. This isn't a word-choice question. Please see our help for single-word-request questions and particularly the checklist at the end.

Also see an offer you can't refuse, a decision that had no real alternative, a choice that is not really a choice, lack of choice, and more

A choice you like and dislike, alternative choice is not really one, choice which is heavily favorable on one side, intentionally unfulfillable request...

Why should this be closed? It seems moderately interesting, although it’s come up before. But then, what hasn’t?

coerce

to persuade someone forcefully to do something that they are unwilling to do:

The court heard that the six defendants had been coerced into making a confession.


Source: Cambridge Dictionary

Someone else made the decision [that affects you] unilaterally...

unilaterally Cambridge Dictionary
in a way that involves doing or deciding something without first asking or agreeing with another person, group, or country
Employers cannot unilaterally change your contract terms


I think you are referring to an imposition:

a situation in which someone expects another person to do something that they do not want to do or that is not convenient.


A colloquial term for being forced into a particular course of action or outcome is to be railroaded. It calls to mind the notion of being on a single track with a predetermined endpoint, with no option to change course. It has a negative connotation, indicating that the person being railroaded does not want to go down this path, and that someone else has forced them into it. The term can be used widely to indicate an unwanted and coerced course of action, but also has a slightly more specific connotation in the legal sphere, suggesting that a defendant's guilty verdict is unfairly a foregone conclusion.

Put upon

taken advantage of as a result of one's good nature; expected or asked
to do too much:
"I've encouraged her to say no if she really feels put upon"

—Oxford Languages

It has less of a negative-connotation than many of the other suggestions, but something that you are being required to do (whether or not you want to do it) is an obligation.

something that you must do

It does not necessarily imply that the initial decision to do something was taken by someone else on your behalf, but it does imply that the option to not do it is no longer yours.
